# Determine game apps in device

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I am currently using Unity to develop some mobile apps. (iOS / Android)
I was wondering if it is *possible to determine the games that are currently installed* on the users' devices?

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to get a list of all installed apps on user mobile. Then you can check those apps against a predefined list of game apps. 
Following is the code to get the list of activities/applications installed on Android :

```
 final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
 mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
 final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Hmmm, what do you mean by a predefined list of game apps?

Comment: You need to create a game list yourself! Thats your predefined list!

Comment: So i have to keep updating the list manually as frequently as i can right. Thanks.